# json encode is output same for all array except one why

Tags: php

if you see my output in first user asad ali 2 line gap between follow and image path how ever other user donot have any gap why? i want to remove this gap in first user thanks for help in advance
only php coding i am using sql query left join between tables
in image table when user upload image data save in database image with user id & image path.if one user upload different images then user id repeated so i want to print only 1 time user id and all related image of same user.same if name repeated in table then i want to print unique in output

MY CODING IS

```
    <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","discover");
if(isset($_REQUEST['user_id']) && isset($_REQUEST['session_id'])){
    $user_id=$_REQUEST['user_id'];
    $session_id=$_REQUEST['session_id'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `users` where user_id='$user_id' AND session_id='$session_id'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($result->num_rows>0)
    {
    $sqlb="SELECT * FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `followers` ON users.user_id=followers.user_id LEFT JOIN `image` ON users.user_id=image.user_id order by users.user_id asc";
$resultb=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlb);
if($resultb->num_rows>0)
 {
    $i=0;
    $user_id=array();
    $result=array();
    // $user_name=array();
    // $user_pic_path=array();
while ($rowb = $resultb->fetch_assoc()) 
{   
    var_dump($rowb);
    $userid = $rowb['user_id'];
    $user_name = $rowb['fast_name']." ".$rowb['last_name'];
    $user_pic_path=$rowb['user_pic_path'];
    $user_follow=$rowb['follower_id'];

    if($user_follow == $user_id)
    {
        $user_followi = TRUE;
    }
    elseif($user_follow !== $user_id)
    {
        $user_followi = FALSE;
    }
    if(!isset($result[$userid]))
    {
        $result[] = array('user_name'=>$user_name,'user_profile_pic'=>$user_pic_path,'follow'=>$user_followi);
    }
    $result[$userid]['image_path'][] = $rowb['image_path'];
}
$response['session']=TRUE;
$response['status']=TRUE;
$response['msg']="user data find successfully";
$response['user_detail']=$result;
echo json_encode($response);
}
 }
 else
    {
        $response['session']=TRUE;
        $response['status']=FALSE;
        $response['msg']="wrong data enter";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }           
}
else
    {
    $response['session']=FALSE;
    $response['status']=FALSE;
    $response['msg']="user does not exists";
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

My OUTPUT IS

```
    // 20180103125211
// http://localhost/1111.php?user_id=2&session_id=953455543

{
  "session": true,
  "status": true,
  "msg": "user data find successfully",
  "user_detail": [
    {
      "user_name": "asad ali",
      "user_profile_pic": "localhost/uploads/image/9152108abc",
      "follow": false
    },
    {
      "image_path": [
        "localhost/uploads/image/7947861Discover All In One.png"
      ]
    },
    {
      "user_name": "asim kabeer",
      "user_profile_pic": "localhost/uploads/image/1952108xyz",
      "follow": false,
      "image_path": [
        "localhost/uploads/image/2152108Mart Zone - All in one.png",
        "localhost/uploads/image/1787860Discover All In One.png"
      ]
    },
    {
      "user_name": "saad hussain",
      "user_profile_pic": "localhost/uploads/image/5152108ytp",
      "follow": false,
      "image_path": [
        "localhost/uploads/image/6547860Discover All In One.png",
        "localhost/uploads/image/1474008Mart Zone - All in one.png"
      ]
    },
    {
      "user_name": "nazeer hussain",
      "user_profile_pic": "localhost/uploads/image/7352108trp",
      "follow": false,
      "image_path": [
        "localhost/uploads/image/1547860Discover All In One.png"
      ]
    },
    {
      "user_name": "asad zahoor",
      "user_profile_pic": "localhost/images/ftftft",
      "follow": false,
      "image_path": [
        "localhost/uploads/image/1081552Mart Zone - All in one.png"
      ]
    },
    {
      "user_name": "ali hussain",
      "user_profile_pic": "localhost/images/sduhsud.png",
      "follow": false,
      "image_path": [
        "localhost/uploads/image/5547860Discover All In One.png"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: please `var_dump` the content of `$rowb` when `$user_name` is asad ali or asim kabeer

Comment: i am using var_dump but not get my desire result

Comment: We need to know the content of `$rowb`, place `var_dump($rowb);` within the while loop and place the result of the requested users in your question.

Comment: i am using this sql query  "SELECT * FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `followers` ON users.user_id=followers.user_id LEFT JOIN `image` ON users.user_id=image.user_id order by users.user_id asc"

Comment: dude, I'm gonna stop helping you out. I've asked for the content of `$rowb` twice and you keep giving me other things.

Comment: i had been given all code & output in question & also give query i donot understand what is contant ? are you want to table schema?

Comment: Like I said: Place `var_dump($rowb);` within the while loop and update your question with that output. `while ($rowb = $resultb->fetch_assoc()) {var_dump($rowb); $userid = $rowb['user_id']; ...`

Comment: using your code and OUTPUT is array(14) {
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["fast_name"]=>
  string(4) "asad"
  ["last_name"]=>
  string(3) "ali"
  ["email"]=>
  string(13) "asad@gmail.xy"
  ["password"]=>
  string(5) "12545"
  ["language"]=>
  string(7) "english"
  ["session_id"]=>
  string(9) "872407452"
  ["user_pic_path"]=>
  string(34) "localhost/uploads/image/9152108abc"
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["follower_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["time_stamp"]=>
  string(19) "2017-11-30 14:51:29"
  ]}

Comment: I need this info of another user which does work correctly. Update your question with the formatted output instead of placing it in a comment. Also, where is the `image-path` element?

Comment: update ok done see plz

Comment: I'm sorry, but I give up. I guess we have a language barrier. Try `$result[$userid] = array('user_name'=>...` instead of `$result[] = array('user_name'=>`

Comment: already used this sequence